# std::list - Sort one item

Tags: c++, list, sorting, stl

Is it possible to sort a list based off one item?

For instance, if I have

```
1,3,2,4,5,6,7 ... 1000000
```

And I know that `3` is the second element, is it possible to efficiently sort `3` into it's correct position between `2` and `4` without re-sorting the entire list?

**EDIT:** I should also note that, in this scenario, it is assumed that the *rest* of the list is already sorted; it is simply the `3` that is now out of place.

Comment: How would you sort `3` if the list contains `2,3,1,...`?

Comment: Do you know the range within the list in which data is unsorted?

Comment: @Graeme No, unfortunately not.

Comment: Selection Sort -   http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Selection_sort

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could simply find that unordered object (O(n)), take the object out (O(1)), find the correct position (O(n)), then insert it again (O(1)).

Assuming C++11,

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::list<int> values {1, 2, 3, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 14};

    auto it = std::is_sorted_until(values.begin(), values.end());
    auto val = *--it;
    // ^ find that object.

    auto next = values.erase(it);
    // ^ remove it.

    auto ins = std::lower_bound(next, values.end(), val);
    // ^ find where to put it back.

    values.insert(ins, val);
    // ^ insert it.

    for (auto value : values) {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Before C++11 you need to [implement `std::is_sorted_until` yourself](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted_until).

Comment: I figured as much (I wondered if there was a built-in way). I guess it'll be a loop to find out where it goes!

Comment: Well, there's [`is_sorted_until`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted_until) and `lower_bound` so you don't need a loop.

Answer (score 1):

For this very limited case, writing your own bubblesort would probably be faster than std::sort.

Answer (score 0):

If you have that level of knowledge, why don't you just swap the items yourself rather than trying to coerce `sort` to do it for you?

Surely that's a better way.

Even if you *don't* know where it has to go, you can find that out quickly, remove it, then insert it at the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use the `insert` method to move the element, but I'd like to know more about the way you calculate its "correct" position: there could be a better suited algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about the traversal possible for a list, it's clearly only end-to-end.  So:

- if you don't know where the mis-ordered element is you have to first scan through the elements one by one until you find it, then
- you can remember the value and delete the out-of-order element from the list, then
- there are two possibilities:

  - that element is greater in your sorting order than any other element you've yet encountered, in which case you need to keep going through the remaining elements until you find the correct place to insert it.
  - the element would belong somewhere amongst the elements you've already passed over, in which case:
  - - you can move backwards, or forwards from the first element again, until you find the correct place to put it.
  - - if you've created some records from your earlier traversal you can instead use it to find the insertion place faster, for example: if you've created a `vector` of list `iterator`s, you can do a binary search in the `vector`.  Vectors of every Nth element, hash tables etc. are all other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

This is If you dont use `std::list`.

With a Selection sort algorthm, you simply  sort items  0 to 3 ( `selectionSort(list,3)`) if you know that thats the range.
Not the entire range till the end.

Sample code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



void selectionSort(int *array,int length)//selection sort function 
{
    int i,j,min,minat;
    for(i=0;i<(length-1);i++)
    {
        minat=i;
        min=array[i];
      for(j=i+1;j<(length);j++) //select the min of the rest of array
      {
          if(min>array[j])   //ascending order for descending reverse
          {
              minat=j;  //the position of the min element 
              min=array[j];
          }
      }
      int temp=array[i] ;
      array[i]=array[minat];  //swap 
      array[minat]=temp;

    }
}

void printElements(int *array,int length) //print array elements
{

    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)     cout<<array[i]<<"  ";
    cout<<" \n ";
}

int main(void)
{

    int list[]={1,3,2,4,5,6};   // array to sort 
    int number_of_elements=6;

    cout<<" \nBefore selectionSort\n";
    printElements(list,number_of_elements);      


    selectionSort(list,3); 

    cout<<" \nAfter selectionSort\n";
    printElements(list,number_of_elements);      


    cout<<" \nPress any key to continue\n";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Before selectionSort
1  3  2  4  5  6

After selectionSort
1  2  3  4  5  6

Press any key to continue
```